# Use array of interface that return from a COM object

Tags: c#, pointers, com, unmanaged-memory

I have a COM dll (native) that I want to use it in my c# project, this dll has a function that get one IntPtr parameter like this :

```
int GetParameter(out paramCount,IntPtr paramInterfaceArray)
```

when I pass a IntPtr variable to the function runs without any error, BUT after call function when I want to use paramInterfaceArray to read array of param Interface I got error **Access violation executing location** . I tried many ways for solve problem but any one works.
can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to show us the full C# declaration (DllImport) and also how the native (C/C++, other) side is defined, and what it does (allocation, pointers, etc.)

Comment: Yes, give us some more info, please.  It is very important how the COM dll exposes the array and what it actually returns.  .NET knows how to handle COM SafeArrays, but native arrays might require extra marshalling flags / efforts.

Comment: I have an COM dll that I was written many years ago by some one and no source code is available for COM dll.
I just Add reference to the COM dll in Visual Studio, and this is sample code:

DLIS dls = new DLIS(); //DLIS is a class from COM dll 
dls.Open(fileName);
....//SOME OTHER CODE
Param list1 = new Param();// Param is an interface from COM dll
GCHandle handle1 = GCHandle.Alloc(list1);
IntPtr parameter = (IntPtr) handle1;
short paramCount ;
dls.GetParameters(ref paramCount, parameter );//GetParameter is the function that runs without any error...

Comment: ...but when I want to access data which parameter refer I got error  Access violation executing location

Comment: First of all, your IntPtr is not defined as out or ref. Pretty hard to get something to return from there. Secondly, you should probably make your function return a SafeArray. However, if you get your way to work, I'd be really interested.